# java circle recognition from an arraylist of points

Tags: java, arraylist, detection, geometry

I currently have an arraylist of points from a freehand drawing on a canvas. I was wondering if there is a simple algorithm to detect if that shape represents a circle.I have already researched this a little and the main items I am pointed at are either the Hough transform or having bitmap images but both of these seem a little over the top for what I need it for. Any pointers to algorithms or implementation would be very helpful.

thanks in advance sansoms,

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? Whether all the points in the list have roughly the same distance to some center, or whether it's a closed loop (not a 350° arc, or a spiral), or both?

Comment: basically to check if it is more like a circle than opposed to being a straight line. It doesn't need to be a perfect circle. just if the user wants to add a circle to a canvas, they can use the mouse to draw a circle and it can be replaced by circle which I can draw with graphic.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y,rectwidth,rectheight));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not know what the user wanted to draw (e.g., a circle, an ellipse, a line, or a rectangle), you could use some basic optimization algorithm to find the shape best matching the hand-drawn points.

- for each basic shape (oval, rectangle, triangle, line, etc.), create a random instance of that shape and measure the error w.r.t. the given points
- optimize each of the shapes (individually) until you have the oval best matching the given points, the rectangle best matching the points, the best triangle, etc.
- pick the shape that has the lowest error and draw it

Comment: Thanks a lot this made it a lot more clear, il get searching for optimisation algoryrithms , this helped a lot

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to know if all the points are on a circle.

As illustrated in the picture, we pick three points A, B, C from the list and compute the origin O of the presumed circle. By checking the distance between O and each point from the list, we can conclude whether these points are on a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/940041/12860

In short: calculate the second derivative. If it is quite constand, it is probably a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment, an easier method to draw a circle is for the user to click the center point, then drag the radius of the circle.  It's a lot less calculation, and easier for the user to draw.

You can do the same thing with a rectangle, or any other convex polygon.