# How to recognize ellipse/ellipsoid from random points? UN-weighted average?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, average, image-recognition, montecarlo

Suppose we are getting random points in 2D (or 3D) which tend to be on ellipse (or ellipsoid). We can't guarantee points are uniformly distributed over ellipse (ellipsoid surface).

The task is to determine ellipse (ellipsoid) parameters, i.e. center location and semi-axes.

We can't take average, because it will be weighted. I mean if points will come preliminary from one side of ellipse, averaging will give wrong results.

So the question is how to `UN-weight` the average?

**UPDATE**

I think in the case of ellipse, the parameters can be determined by statistical quantities like moments. Can they?

Comment: Looks like a case of [Curve Fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting). Depending on the data and requirements, there may be different approaches. Some kind of a simple genetic algorithm might work.

Comment: Related question: [java circle recognition from an arraylist of points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13452821/1639625)

Comment: are all of the points known to be on the curve/surface, or is this like an image analysis problem where you first need to identify which points to include?

Answer (score 1):

Any ellipse can be fully defined using 5 points (see a detailed reasoning [here](http://sarcasticresonance.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/how-many-points-does-it-take-to-define/)). So, if you know that the points are error-free and on an ellipse you can take any 5 points of your set and get the ellipse parameters.

If the points can have an error component you can fit an ellipse on the data set using something like gradient descent. As an error function I'd use the sum of the squares of the distances between the data points and the ellipse. For example, for each data point you can take the line defined by it and the current ellipse center, intersect it with the ellipse and consider the distances from the point to the closest of the 2 intersection points.

Finally, [here's](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3215-fitellipse/content/fit_ellipse.m) a Matlab package that implements something along those lines. The function documentation is also very informative.

Comment: I implemented something like this recently, so I can confirm that it works in principle. I had noisy data falling on a portion of an arbitrary 3D ellipsoid. I created a 3x4 matrix to transform that ellipsoid to a unit sphere, initialized to an identity matrix, and used gradient descent on each of the matrix coefficients in round-robin fashion. As error I used the difference of the transformed samples from unit length. Provided my initial data spanned a "large enough" swath of the ellipsoid, it correctly converged on a stable, reasonable fit. It wasn't fast, but as a proof of concept it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Any point on the ellipse will obey the equation
    x^2 / a ^ 2 + y ^ 2 / b ^ 2 = 1
If you have two such points, it should be solvable using simultaneous equations method

Comment: That equation applies only when the ellipse's axes are x and y, which may not be the case. The question explicitly states that the parameters are unknown.