# Detect the circular (not exact circle) path algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geometry

I am receiving a path - list of x,y coordinates from a touchevent. How can I detect this path forms a circular path (not a complete or exact circle)? Is there any algorithm or way to detect this?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13452821/1639625), but not actually a duplicate. I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13454226/1639625) might help.

Comment: Since even a straight line looks like part of an incomplete path of a huge circle, you will need a way to decide if something is "circular enough".  I suggest using an angle threshold -- e.g. if the path looks like 270 degrees' worth of circle path, call it a circular path, otherwise don't.

Comment: What are examples of what you would call a circular path, and what would you like to say is not a circular path? I suspect that you don't need an exact geometric circle, but would following an ellipse count? What about following a circle for 180 degrees? How about if someone writes an 'e' on the screen? Gesture detection is common.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a paper with a summary of various methods for fitting circles to data: http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/kerryj/kjones/circles.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

Suppose I have the points of a semicircle:

```
val angles180 = (0 to 180 by 45).map(_ / 180.0 * Pi)
val points = angles180.map { a => (math.cos(a), math.sin(a)) }
```

I can take the combinations of the subsets with 3 elements:

```
val pointsList = points.combinations(3).toList
```

And [locate the center and radius of a circle given only three points on the circle](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gcg6/RCir.htm), for each subset in `pointsList`:

```
val circles = for {
  p <- pointsList
} yield calculateCircle(p)
```

Where:

```
case class Circle(x: Double, y: Double, r: Double)

def calculateCircle(points: Seq[(Double, Double)]): Circle = {
  val Seq((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)) = points

  val mr = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
  val mt = (y3 - y2) / (x3 - x2)

  val x0 = (mr * mt * (y3 - y1) + mr * (x2 + x3) - mt * (x1 + x2)) / (2 * (mr - mt))
  val y0 = -1.0 / mr * (x0 - (x1 + x2) / 2) + (y1 + y2) / 2

  val r = math.sqrt((x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0) + (y1 - y0) * (y1 - y0))

  Circle(x0, y0, r)
}
```

You should check for invalid circles (maybe the points are colinear and give invalid results):

```
def isInvalid(circle: Circle) = 
  (circle.x.isNaN || circle.y.isNaN || circle.r.isNaN)

val validCircles = circles.filterNot(isInvalid)
```

Although valid, these circles could (will) have different data. You should see if the calculated circles are similar to each other.

One way of doing it is to see if their data fall inside the interval of `(m - x . s, m + x . s)`, where `m` is the mean and `s` is the standard deviation. For `x == 2.58`, 99% of the data lie inside the interval.
You could check if each of the circles data lie inside and if they don't, it's not a circle. Remember, we do that for the `x` and `y` positions of the center of the circle and for the radius `r`, and it is only good if all three are good.

```
def looksLikeACircle(circles: Seq[Circle]) = {
  val resultsLists = circles.map { c => List(c.x, c.y, c.r) }.transpose

  val cis = resultsLists.map(interval99)

  val good = resultsLists.zip(cis).map { case (values, ci) => withinInterval(values, ci) }
  val allGood = good.reduceLeft { (acc, v) => acc && v }

  allGood
}


val allGood = looksLikeACircle(validCircles)
```

Where:

```
def mean(values: Seq[Double]) = values.sum / values.size

def standardDeviation(values: Seq[Double]) = {
  val m = mean(values)

  math.sqrt(values.map { v => (v - m) * (v - m) }.sum / (values.size - 1))
}

def interval99(values: Seq[Double]) = {
  val m = mean(values)
  val d = (2.58 * standardDeviation(values))

  (m - d, m + d)
}

def withinInterval(values: Seq[Double], ci: (Double, Double)) =
  values.forall { v => ci._1 <= v && v <= ci._2 }
```

Well, it looks like the points make a circle, but maybe it's just math. Given a large enough radius, a true circle could appear as a straight line in the window. The question is: could the user make a circle with these points in a window?

You could check if the mean circle is inside the window's boundary:

```
case class Window(x: Double, y: Double, w: Double, h: Double)

def calculateMeanCircle(circles: Seq[Circle]) = {
  val resultsLists = circles.map { c => List(c.x, c.y, c.r) }.transpose

  val Seq(xm, ym, rm) = resultsLists.map(mean)

  Circle(xm, ym, rm)
}

def isCircleFit(circle: Circle, window: Window) = {
  def isWithinBounds(value: Double, bounds: (Double, Double)) = {
    bounds._1 <= value && value <= bounds._2
  }

  val (xMin, xMax) = (circle.x - circle.r, circle.x + circle.r)
  val (yMin, yMax) = (circle.y - circle.r, circle.y + circle.r)

  val horizontalBounds = (window.x, window.x + window.w)
  val verticalBounds = (window.y, window.y + window.h)

  val isInside =
    isWithinBounds(xMin, horizontalBounds) && isWithinBounds(xMax, horizontalBounds) &&
    isWithinBounds(yMin, verticalBounds) && isWithinBounds(yMax, verticalBounds)

  isInside
}

val meanCircle = calculateMeanCircle(validCircles)
```

Finally, for the `points` in the start of this long post (hope you are still here) and a `window`:

```
val window = Window(0, 0, 600, 800)

println("Looks like a circle? " + allGood)
println(meanCircle)
println(window)
println("Is mean circle fit? " + isCircleFit(meanCircle, window))
```

We get:

```
Looks like a circle? true
Circle(-8.088567489053774E-18,4.4408920985006264E-17,1.0)
Window(0.0,0.0,600.0,800.0)
Is mean circle fit? false
```

Well just one quadrant could be drawn by these points inside this window, so no fit.

What if:

```
val points5 = angles180.map { a => (window.w / 2 + math.cos(a), window.h / 2 + math.sin(a)) }
```

It's better now (it's in the center of the window):

```
Looks like a circle? true
Circle(300.0,400.0,1.0000000000000144)
Window(0.0,0.0,600.0,800.0)
Is mean circle fit? true
```

How about these points that *almost* form a circle with center in `(0, 0)` and radius `r == 1`:

```
val points = Seq(
  ( 1.0,  0.0),
  ( 0.0,  1.1),
  (-0.9,  0.0),
  (-0.1, -1.0)
)
```

Well, it's look like one but it doesn't fit again of course (but you see the point):

```
Looks like a circle? true
Circle(0.05805243445692886,0.07674497786857344,1.0288200278337032)
Window(0.0,0.0,600.0,800.0)
Is mean circle fit? false
```

You would need to test it thoroughly, as I haven't, and maybe tweak it a little (or a lot), but you can take it from here, I hope.

Also, I see that one of the tags as `java`, but you shouldn't have a hard time to convert it, I suppose.