# Determine if a Path describes a circle

Tags: java, geometry

I am trying to test if a path or polyline describes a circle in java. How can i do this? I am thinking about testing if the biggest distance between two points is nearly the same for all points on the path (with some mistake in mind). Can this work? What other possibilities did I have to check that?

Comment: see if this helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236963/detect-the-circular-not-exact-circle-path-algorithm

Comment: You mean, for each point, find the distance to the farthest other point? If these distances are in a narrow range, we have approximately a circle. I think it would work.

Comment: Take the points (-5, 0), (3, -4), (3, 4) and (5, 0). They are on a perfect circle, only unevenly distributed. Your distances will be 10, 8.94, 8.94 and 10. If this is close enough, it seems you are there.

Comment: Can the path/polyline represent a circular arc (e.g. a semicircle)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2D...

1. **compute bbox**

   so find min and max `x,y` coordinate values from all the sample points `x[i],y[i]` you got. Lets call them `x0,y0,x1,y1` where `x0<=x1` and `y0<=y1`
2. **compute center of circle `cx,cy`**

   simply center of bbox so:

   ```
   cx = 0.5*(x1+x0)
   cy = 0.5*(y1+y0)
   ```
3. **compute radius**

   if you got really a circle then bbox should be square so

   ```
   fabs((x1-x0)-(y1-y0)) <= zero_threshold
   ```

   if not you do not have a circle. If yes radius is

   ```
   r = ~0.5*(x1-x0) = ~0.5*(y1-y0)
   ```

   so do the average ...

   ```
   r = 0.25*(x1-x0 + y1-y0)
   ```
4. **check for deviation from circle**

   compute max abs difference ...

   ```
    d = max ( fabs( (x[i]-cx)^2 + (y[i]-cy)^2 - r^2) )
   ```

   if `d > max_radius_difference_threshold^2` then you do not have a circle.

Also check this out:

- [Algorithms: Ellipse matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36054594/2521214)

There are also another tell tels like

- if you know radius and path length then it should match the circle circumference
- avg point of **uniformly** sampled **closed** circular path is also the center
- angle between line segments of **uniformly** sampled circular path is constant
- circle is convex only

Answer (score -1):

general equation of  circle is `a^2 + b^2=r^2` with center (0,0); where r is the radius of the circle and a and b the coordinates of point put in a and b and get the values of r if the value of r is same for all the values of a and b then the path is a circle .
Note:- for a center at a point (h,k) equation changes to :-

```
(a-h)^2+(b-k)^2=r^2;
```